# How to show options according to user permission in PHP? Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web, permissions, user-permissions

how to show options according to user permission in PHP?
For example, that only administrators enter to "xx" menu.

This is my table

> Permissions_users

[Table Permissions_users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok4hv.png)

And this is my table

> users

[Table Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajk31.png)

Comment: When user login, try adding privilege into session then check it by `if($_SESSION['priviledge'] == 'teacher'){ //do this } `

Comment: You use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) to allow different user roles.

Comment: Now I have if ($ _ SESSION ['privilege'] == 'teacher'), but what do I do if I create a new user with any name(for example, teacher2) with only read permissions, or read and delete, or just delete? How do I control what he can see according to his permits?

Answer (score 0):

alter user table add one column:is_admin(0/1).according to this value to show or hide options.